# maven release prepare tagging incorrect revision number

Tags: maven-release-plugin

Hy, I am using 3.2.5 maven.

I have a problem with releasing. I use the release:prepare to Tagging from trunk and create version without snapshot. The preapre run clean and verify by default after Transforming but I modified this setting to celan. So the prepapre goal dont create build.
I use release:perform to checkout from tag and build. I woudlike add manifest.mf with svn revision number to build.

This is ok but the revision number in build equal the revison number of Trunk.

For example: Tag revision = 7000 and Trunk revision=7001. When I make a build from tag it make revision number 7001.

I chechked the Tag manualy and create build with install and the revision number as soon as than perform.

I tagging manualy and create build with install and the revision number correct so the revision number eqaul the revision number of tag.

It visible the revision number of tag and trunk in svn. When revison number of tag 7000 but I get 7001 in build (tagging with prepare).

Can you help me?

Thank you!